# find element using jquery by knowing data- attribute id

Tags: javascript, jquery

my a element has id myId and besides other data- attributes has data-myControlId like

```
<a id="myId" onclick="Test(this)" ... data-... data-... data-myControlId="999" role="button">
 Click me
</a>
```

since button with this myId is rendered multiple times in foreach loop, how can I recognized clicked element by its `data-controlId` since **this attribute is unique**. I want to recognize it using jquery inside my javascript function so I can remove css class like

```
 function Test(myObj){
        var clickedItem = ...
        clickedItem.removeClass("myClass");
    };
```

Comment: You do know an ID needs to be unique right?

Comment: This question is irrelevant as ID's must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
$('[data-myControlId="' + numberToLookFor + '"]');
```

... but, as rightly noticed, you can't have more than one element with the same ID. And, frankly speaking, I fail to understand what's wrong with treating *ID* as a kind of compound key attribute. Like this:

```
<a id="control-999">Click me</a>
```

Finding the corresponding element will be trivial then:

```
$('#control-' + numberToLookFor);
```

Answer (score 0):

First **ID of an element must be UNIQUE**...(don't use the ID attribute unless you can keep them unique because it won't make any sense with duplicate values, in this case you can just remove it)

Second since you are passing `this` to `Test` it is the clicked dom element reference, so you can use it to get the jQuery object reference like

```
function Test(myObj){
    var clickedItem = $(this)
    clickedItem.removeClass("myClass");
};
```

Third, I would recommend using jQuery event handlers instead of using inline once

---

Add a common class to all of the target elements like

```
<a id="myId" class="myclass" ... data-... data-... data-myControlId="999" role="button">
    Click me
</a>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.myclass').click(function () {
        var clickedItem = $(this);
        clickedItem.removeClass("myClass");
    })
})
```